# Rate of decrease in population

Tags: integration

The rate of decrease of the population of a species is inversely proportional to the size of the population. 10 years ago there were 100, and 5 years ago that had dropped to 80. What is it now and how long until the species goes extinct?
..........I think I need to do some integration, but I'm lost as to the equation I need to write.

Answer (score 0):

If the population is $n$, rate of decrease is $\frac {dn}{dt}$ so you are given $$\frac {dn}{dt}=-\frac kn$$ where $k$ is the proportionality constant.  You are given $n(0)$ and $n(5)$ and should be able to evaluate $k$ from that.